# Independence in Coupon Collecting Problem

Tags: probability, coupon-collector

If $T_i$ is the number of cards that we draw from a deck before seeing the $(i+1)$th new card (after seeing the ith new card), how can I show that Then $T_i$ and $T_j$ are independent (for i≠j)? I know the definition of independence, but I don't know how to get a workable second definition to compare to $P(T_j)P(T_i)$.

Answer (score -1):

In both cases you have a geometric distribution.  If there are $n$ cards in total, the chance of success after having seen $i$ cards is $\frac {n-i}n$.  This clearly is independent of $j$

Comment: I understand that it should be true, but how could I prove that the two random variables are independent, formally?

Comment: I think this is a fine proof.  You have a value for $P(T_i)$ that you can compute, then just point out that it does not depend on $T_j$